# Show all tickets that have been assigned to department A and got re-assigned to department B

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find out what tickets have been assigned to department A first and got re-assigned to department B.
For our tickets we have a log-table in our database, that saves all actions that have taken place for a ticket before it was closed.

### What I need

What I need now are all tickets, that have been re-assigned from department A to department B. It doesn't matter if the tickets got closed by department B or even if department B re-assigned the ticket back to department A. An example for this you can see in the table below in row 3 and 4.

### What I have

```
SELECT
    inc.incident_ref
    , sd.SERV_DEPT_N
    , actr.DATE_ACTIONED
    , actt.ACT_TYPE_N
FROM
    act_reg                actr
    INNER JOIN SA.ACT_type actt
        ON actr.ACT_TYPE_ID = actt.ACT_TYPE_ID
    INNER JOIN incident    inc
        ON inc.incident_id = actr.INCIDENT_ID
    INNER JOIN serv_dept   sd
        ON actr.SERV_DEPT_ID = sd.SERV_DEPT_ID
WHERE
    actr.DATE_ACTIONED > '31.07.2020'
    AND actt.ACT_TYPE_N = 'internal assignment'
    AND sd.SERV_DEPT_N = 'A'
    AND sd.SERV_DEPT_N = 'B';
```

(I know that I can't work like that, because there is no entry that has department A and B)

What the log-data looks like for a specific ticket (the query above without the where statement):

| act_reg_id | incident_id | serv_dept_n | date_actioned | act_type_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1438113 | C | 02.12.2020 17:22 | closed |
| 2 | 1438113 | A | 14.11.2020 10:01 | internal assignment |
| 3 | 1438113 | B | 14.11.2020 09:13 | internal assignment |
| 4 | 1438113 | A | 11.11.2020 15:03 | internal assignment |
| 5 | 1438113 | A | 11.11.2020 06:44 | investigation |
| 6 | 1438113 | A | 10.11.2020 14:00 | internal assignment |

The action type "internal assignment" doesn't only take place when a new department gets assigned to the ticket, but also when the tickets gets re-assigned to a new user within the same department.

What (part of) the log-table (*act_reg*) looks like (the other tables I only need so my result will include actual names and not just ids, so they shouldn't be of much importance for my question):

| act_reg_id | incident_id | serv_dept_id | date_actioned | act_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1438113 | 100 | 02.12.2020 17:22 | 1 |
| 2 | 1438113 | 122 | 14.11.2020 10:01 | 5 |
| 3 | 1438113 | 4 | 14.11.2020 09:13 | 5 |
| 4 | 1438113 | 122 | 11.11.2020 15:03 | 5 |
| 5 | 1438113 | 122 | 11.11.2020 06:44 | 3 |
| 6 | 1438113 | 122 | 10.11.2020 14:00 | 5 |

Comment: "The table".  Your question refers to five tables.

Comment: Are you sure serv_dept_n refers to the department the item was reassigned to or is it the department that took whatever action was taken?  If it doesn't record the department it was reassigned from and to you won't be able to query that.

Comment: @Bee_Rii as far as I know it doesn't specifically say what department the ticket was reassigned to, only what department took action. So I imagine I would have to search for all tickets where department A took action first and department B took action after. But I don't know how to do that (or if it's even possible).

Comment: @Acinogara can a department take action on a ticket even if they aren't assigned it?  So could department B close a ticket or assign it to department C if it was currently assigned to A?

With the data you have presented you can certainly get a list of all tickets where X department reassigned a ticket before Y department took some action but that might not be the exact question you are trying to answer.

Comment: @Bee_Rii you are right. A department that isn't assigned to the ticket can still take action. It doesn't seem to be a problem tho, my colleague wants all tickets where B took action after A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you are looking for all tickets that were assigned to A and then assigned to B no matter where in the workflow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT indident_id
FROM act_reg a1
WHERE 
  sd.SERV_DEPT_N = 'B'
  AND EXISTS ( 
               SELECT 1 FROM act_reg a2 
               where a2.SERV_DEPT_N = 'A' 
               AND a2.date_actioned < a1.date_actioned
               AND a1.indident_id = a2.indident_id
             )
```

Comment: you would need to include the incident_id  in the exists statement.

Comment: Yeah missed that part